# Onset of Autophagy

Tags: cell-biology

Fasting and Intermittent Fasting (IF) have been proven to start autophagy (cellular self-digestion). How long does the average man and woman have to wait for autophagy to begin? Does diet prior to fasting effect the onset of autophagy? And lastly, does longer fasting produce more efficient autophagy than IF?

Comment: Would you happen to have a reference for your first statement?

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21471734; http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20534972; http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19200897;

Comment: Thanks for the links.  This appears to be a related question that might help: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/does-intermittent-fasting-improve-immune-function-through-autophagy

Comment: Does not quite answer my questions. I am more interested in how long after a fast starts does the mechanism of cellular self-digestion begin.

Comment: Yes, but the references might point you in the right direction.  The main issue I see is that a lot of work has been done in non-human animals -- you (or someone else who is familiar with this area, which is not me) might have better luck looking up the signaling pathways involved involved and seeing when and how they turn on in response to fasting.  Another keyword to consider is "starvation".